# How to make Typescript compiler know when a variable is not null?

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescrip 3.4 with React and I'm trying to load the Youtube Iframe API with this code

```
const tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "www.youtube.com/player_api";
const firstScriptTag = document.querySelector("script");
if (firstScriptTag != null) {
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}
```

Even though I'm checking if the variable is null, React will refuse to compile since the TS compiler is throwing the *Object is possibly 'null'* error

I have also tried using the non-null assertion operator ("!") like this

`firstScriptTag!.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);`

And the problem persists.

I know I can get rid of it by setting `strict=false` in the *tsconfig* file but I want to force myself to write good quality code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jcalz You are right! Thanks. Instead of a comment maybe you should make this an answer so I can mark it a accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is on `firstScriptTag.parentNode`.  You have to check both `firstScriptTag` and `firstScriptTag.parentNode` before you can safely call a method on `firstScriptTag.parentNode`:

```
if (firstScriptTag && firstScriptTag.parentNode) {
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); // no error
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck.